# Flask losing css on a second return render_template

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, flask, jinja2

My flask app renders_template index.html when started

```
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    user = {'username' : 'Pinto'}
    bios = []
    return render_template('index.html', title='JAF', user=user, bios=bios)
```

index.html has static/css/style.css linked in the head and the CSS loads on initial render_tempate. However when using jquery to load a jinja2 template into index.html I lose all styling.

main.js

```
$("#click_render").click(function() {
    $("html").load("/click_render");
})
```

routes.py (data replaces with place holders)

```
@app.route('/click_render')
def click_render():
    user = {'username' : 'Pinto'}
    bios = [
        {dataset1},
        {dataset2},
        {dataset3},
    ]
    return render_template('index.html', title='JAF', user=user, bios=bios)
```

index.html (head.html loads css, I also had the same problem before moving the head to a template)

```
<html>
    <head>
        {% include 'head.html' %}
    </head>
    <body style='margin:0'>
        <button type="button" id='click_render'>route/click_render</button>
        <h1>Hello, {{ user.username }}!</h1>
        <div class="included">
            {% include 'included.html' %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

included.html

```
{% for bio in bios %}
    <div>
        <p>{{ bio.name }} </p>
        <p>{{ bio.age }} </p>
        <p>{{ bio.height }}</p>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I do get the following error in my browser:

> jquery.min.js:4 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: I think i have narrowed down the problem. When I render the new template, the "<body>" tags are removed from the new rendering. I believe this has something to do with jinja2 templates. trying to look into using extend and blocks however i cant seem to get that to work.